# merge dictionaries in python with common key/value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am looking to merge dictionaries in Python with dictionaries that have a common value then key. Currently, I have a nasty loop inside of a loop inside of a loop. There has to be a better way...

What I have is one dictionary with a single digit key and a list of numbers for that value, then a second dictionary with a key that corresponds with one of the numbers in the value list and a float associated with that number. They are formatted like this (although much larger):

```
dict1 = {0:[3, 5, 2, 7], 1:[1, 4, 0, 6]}
dict2 = {0:0.34123, 1:0.45623, 2:0.76839, 3:0.32221, 4:0.871265, 5:0.99435, 6:0.28665, 7:0.01546}
```

And I would like to merge them so they look like this:

```
dict3 = {0:[0.32221, 0.99435, 0.76839, 0.01546], 1:[0.45623, 0.871265, 0.034123, 0.28665]}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this than several nested for loops? Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Merge them in what way? I really don't see some any obvious correlation between the numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a nested list comprehension inside a dict comprehension:

```
dict3 = {k: [dict2[i] for i in v] for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

This will basically iterate through all `k/v`-combinations within the first dictionary. The `k` is kept as the key for the resulting dictionary, and the `v` is a list of all indices in `dict2` which values should be used. So we iterate through the elements in `v` and collect all items from `dict2` we want to take, combine those in a list (using the list comprehension) and use that result as the value of the result dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> dict1 = {0:[3, 5, 2, 7], 1:[1, 4, 0, 6]}
>>> dict2 = {0:0.34123, 1:0.45623, 2:0.76839, 3:0.32221, 4:0.871265, 5:0.99435, 6:0.28665, 7:0.01546}
>>> {k:[dict2[m] for m in v] for k, v in dict1.items()}
{0: [0.32221, 0.99435, 0.76839, 0.01546], 1: [0.45623, 0.871265, 0.34123, 0.28665]}
```

Comment: You converged on the same answer as @poke above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

And yet another dictionary comprehension, but with map...

```
dict3={k: map(lambda x: dict2[x],dict1[k]) for k in dict1.iterkeys()}
```